# How to combine ajax and CORS to send json requests to another domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying to get info from a webservice hosted on another domain. Originally i only used ajax, but then i realised that this doesn't work cus of security reasons. Afterwards i learned that i can use CORS to build around this problem, the problem is i don't get it working. Any sugestions?

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:34887//Login",
    data: '{"username":"Administrator","password":""}',
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[1]);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

php code with CORS:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:34887/');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

errors i get:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:34887/Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5050' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

which is the same error i get when not using CORS.
(online examples of CORS are welcome)

Comment: Site A wants to call a web service on Site B. Site B needs to set those access control headers to allow Site A to call the service. Is that what you're doing in your test?

Comment: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is listing the origin of the endpoint you're **calling**. It should list the origin of the page **making** the call.

Comment: i don't quite understand CORS yet, i have a site that requests from a webservice, this webservice is able to post all the data in my sql server, now i am trying to access and edit this data from my localhost:5050, so i put the CORS in the php of the site on localhost:5050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two servers - `Server A` (let it be `http://localhost:5050`) and Server B (let it be `http://localhost:34887/`) and you are trying to run ajax from a website that runs from `Server A` to `Server B`

```
Website on Server A ===AjaxRequest==> Server B
```

Then `Server B` should response to the request from the website that runs on `Server A` using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the value of `Server A` in it:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Server A');
```

Which is:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5050');
```

This code should be run within `Server B` to accept requests from `Server A`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, correct, I'll update the answer with better terminology :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, let me know if the current explanation is better. Thanks!

Comment: i think i understand, i thought i had the put the headers on site A (localhost:5050)

Comment: @sansactions: What you should do in your code running on `localhost:34887` is read the `origin` of the request from the headers, decide if you want to accept that origin, and if so echo that origin back as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If you don't want to grant access, don't send back any CORS headers at all. That way, you're not advertising who you allow access to.

Comment: @Dekel: Totally up to you, but I'd leave Server A out of it entirely. "If you have a page whose origin is `http://localhost:5050` (the client) that needs to access a server endpoint at `http://localhost:34887` (the server endpoint), then the server needs to respond to a request for that endpoint with a header allowing the origin of the page making the request." (or similar).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is this possible in any other way, or from code that is running on the 5050, the problem is i have a program that runs the data to 34887, i can't find a way to force a php file on that server

Comment: The server that runs on 34887 is the one that should return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. It doesn't matter if it runs php/python/perl or any other language - in order for the browser (viewing the website on 5050) to accept the response from the server (on 34887) you **must** return that header.

Comment: @Dekel ok, i understand now, i will look into it on how i will do it, for the moment running chrome like this would help 2 right (chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security), only for testing purposes

Comment: If it's only for tests I guess it's ok, however I really recommend you to fix that issue (and not to find workarounds).

Comment: i will discuss with the creator of the webservice, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Dekel sorry forgot it, thnx

Comment: @Dekel a short question, is it possible to do json requests with php code instead and will this still give problems with cross domain connection? thnx

Comment: If the requests are done by the server you don't really need to care about CORS.

Answer (score 0):

you could add * to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin so it would be:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Only if they want it wide open to the whole world. Even if they do want to (and there's no indication they do in the question), it's **really** important to flag that up if you suggest doing it.